# Android App keeps on crashing upon new Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

So I've got this error code: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference`

The line: `Intent callMode = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IncallActivity.class);`

What I'm trying to do is to set a new activity when I receive a call. The following function is what should "switch" to that activity.

```java
public void callMode() {
    Intent callMode = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IncallActivity.class);
    startActivity(callMode);
}
```

And it is located inside of the MainActivity class, outside of the onCreate function.
When I try to put it inside of the onCreate function (without `public void callMode()` of course) it works, but that's not the goal.

I'm trying to activate this new activity from another class, which listens for calls.

```java
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    IncallActivity incallActivity = new IncallActivity();
    public MainActivity mainActivity;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            mainActivity.callMode();
        } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            incallActivity.endCallMode();
        }
    }
}
```

So why does this error show up?

Comment: `mainActivity` is `null` and `incallActivity` is invalid. You cannot create instances of an activity yourself. If you want to show an activity from this receiver, call `startActivity()` to display it.

Comment: So then, how do I fix it?

Comment: Get rid of `mainActivity`. Get rid of `incallActivity`. Replace `mainActivity.callMode()` and `incallActivity.endCallMode()` with `startActivity()` calls. You are passed a `Context` that you can use with `startActivity()`.

Comment: context.startActivity(new Intent(context, IncallActivity.class));

Comment: Still crashes. Not sure if I'm doing the right thing, but it crashes with context.startActivity();

`context.startActivity(new Intent((Context) MainActivity, IncallActivity.class));`

`private Object MainActivity;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it.

You need to add a `public static Context context` to your code, and then in onCreate, do `context = getBaseContext();`

From there you can launch the second activity from any class you'd like.